# How do I test a component that depends on the useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have below component in my app:

```
export default function SomeComponent() {
  const [errorDescription, setErrorDescription] = useState('');
  const initCustomHook = useCustomHook(setErrorDescription);
  return (
    <SomeContainer>
      <Stack alignItems={'center'} spacing={2}>
        <Typography>Some text</Typography>
        {!errorDescription && (
          <CircularProgress data-testid={'circular-progress'} />
        )}
        <FormHelperText sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }} error>
          {errorDescription}
        </FormHelperText>
      </Stack>
    </SomeContainer>
  );
}
```

I want to write a test to check whether, when the error description has a value, such as 'Error', it will be displayed in this component.

How do I mock a useState hook with Jest? What should such a test look like?

Comment: Typically you avoid mocking component internals if possible. That stuff is typically  considered "private" and so doesn't form part of the normal public interface, which is the UI it produces. Typically you'd use jest with something like react-testing-library, where you get the component into the state the same way a user would (dom interaction), or provide it via the props. In your example, `setErrorDescription` is never called, so there's no actual real-end user behaviour to test (missing?). So until that's added, there is no behaviour to test at all.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one line where setErrorDescription is passed to customHook.

Answer (score 0):

To see what happens to a component based on a change of state, developers use [React Developer Tools](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi).
i suggest you read about it to understand what it does.
after installing the [extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

You will get two new tabs in your Chrome DevTools: "⚛️ Components" and "⚛️ Profiler".

You can alter the state from your Chrome Devtools, and the component will display as it should at that specific state.

open Chrome Devtools select "⚛️ Components"
[You will see something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAb5v.png)
now change state from DevTools your component will react to it, the component will display as it should at that specific state.

[here you can see CircularProgress is not in the React component tree, and the error can be seen on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bObN.png)
see state has set to something from the DevTools.